# How do I prove $(y+c+b)^\lambda + (x+c+b)^\lambda \geq (y+x+c)^\lambda + (c+2b)^\lambda$ for $0<=\lambda<=1$ $\forall y \geq x \geq b>0, c \geq b$

Tags: inequality

Someone has shown that $(y+c+b)^\lambda + (x+c+b)^\lambda \geq (y+x+c)^\lambda + (c+2b)^\lambda$ $\forall y \geq x \geq b>0, c \geq b$ is true for $\lambda = 0.5$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4336563). The proof is also trivial for $\lambda=1$ or $\lambda=0$.

Interestingly, I tried different million of combinations for $x,y,c,b,\lambda$, and the inequality is always true while $0\leq\lambda\leq1$.

Any help or hint? I would be grateful!

Comment: Please tell us who the "somebody" is, and the work resulting from your trials.  Please understand this site is not a "do my work for me" service.  You need to provide far more context.  [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1|128.8139).  Please read it.

Comment: Sorry, I added the link but I did not say that the user VTand has shown the result for $\lambda = 0.5$. The question was pure curiosity. I'll read your link, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x) = (x+c+b)^{\lambda}$. It is enough to show that $$f(y)+f(x) \geq f(x+y-b)+f(b).$$ An equivalent way of saying this is $$f(x)-f(b) \geq f(x+y-b) - f(y)$$ and $$\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b} \geq \frac{f(x+y-b) - f(y)}{x-b}$$ since $x>b$ ($x=b$ case follows if we check the original inequality.) Since $c+b > 0$, $f$ is differentiable for positive real $x$. Thus by mean value theorem, $\frac{f(x)-f(b)}{x-b} = f'(c_1)$ and $\frac{f(x+y-b) - f(y)}{x-b} = f'(c_2)$, where $c_1\in (b,x)$ and $c_2 \in (y,x+y-b)$. Note that $c_1 \leq c_2$. Since $0<\lambda <1$, $f'(x)$ is a decreasing function if $x$ is positive, therefore $f'(c_1) \geq f'(c_2)$, concluding the proof.

Comment: You made it look easy! I was days trying to prove it. I never thought of using the mean value theorem. Nice tool!